# How to change the grails version in eclipse?

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I am using

http://spring.io/tools/ggts

for grails development. But the version that comes with this eclipse bundle is above 2.2.0. I need to change the grails version and point it to 2.2.0. I have downloaded grails version 2.2.0. How can i change the grails in the eclipse so that it points to 2.2.0? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure as many versions of Grails as you like inside of GGTS.  Open the preferences and navigate to Groovy -> Grails.  Click the "Add" button to add new versions of Grails.  Now when you create projects you can select which of the installed versions you want to use.  You can also associate different versions of Grails with already existing projects.

I hope that helps.